# 2nd order recurrence relation with constant coefficients

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

I need to find the general solution to the following second order linear recurrence relation:

a<sub>n</sub>=a<sub>n-1</sub>+2a<sub>n-2</sub>-2n+1 for n≥2

I am looking for the auxiliary equation to do so and so far have t<sup>2</sup>=t+2 but I'm not sure what to do about the -2n+1 part.

Comment: You need a particular solution. What happens if you put $a_n=n$? You get $a_n-a_{n-1}-2a_{n-2}=-2n+$ something you don't want. How do you fix that?

Answer (score 1):

Try to find a particular solution of the form
$$
An^2+Bn+C
$$
and add it to the solution of the homogeneous part.

Answer (score 1):

First you solve homogeneous equation:
$$a_n=a_{n-1}+2a_{n-2}$$
By letting $a_n=x^n$ you will get:
$$x^n=x^{n-1}+2x^{n-2} \Rightarrow x=-1;2.$$
So the particular solution is:
$$a_n=C_1(-1)^n+C_2\cdot 2^n.$$
General solution you will search in the form:
$$a_n=C_1(-1)^n+C_2\cdot 2^n+An+B.$$
When you plug this into the initial nonhomogeneous equation, you will get:
$$An+B=A(n-1)+B+2(A(n-2)+B)-2n+1 \Rightarrow A=1; \ \ B=2.$$
Hence the general solution is:
$$a_n=C_1(-1)^n+C_2\cdot 2^n+n+2.$$
You can find $C_1$ and $C_2$ if $a_0$ and $a_1$ are given.